# The right way to deploy non-servable resources

Tags: tomcat

I want to include some files in my WAR that the classes can get to but that Tomcat will never serve directly.  I can think of lots of ways I *could* do this but I'm pretty sure there's a canonical way I'm *supposed* to be doing this.  References appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having files under `WEB-INF` seems to be the standard in [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_load_a_properties_file.3F) as well as other app servers.

[Sun's official-enough article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Servlets/servletapi/) says:

> The WEB-INF directory is special. The
>   files there are not served directly to
>   the client; instead, they contain Java
>   classes and configuration information
>   for the Web app. The directory behaves
>   like a jar file's META-INF directory;
>   it contains metainformation about the
>   archive contents.